# Careers PDF, projects and interests only shows Stack Overflow while profile also shows Programmers and UX

Tags: bug, jobs, profile-page, pdf

Using the create PDF link you can generate a resume from your Careers profile.

However, the "Projects & Interests" section only shows Stack Overflow information, while my profile also includes [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour) and [UX](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour).

PDF:
[image: PDF Projects and interests section]

Profile:
[image: Public profile page]

How can I get the PDF to include the Programmers and UX information?